# Filter Object by array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have an object data coming from service, i want to filter out some items based on key-value, also it's not only one item but multiple items to remove;

```
var dataFromServce = [{
    kod: 1000, teur: 'do0',    
    kod: 1001, teur: 'do1',   
    kod: 1002, teur: 'do2',    
    kod: 1003, teur: 'do3'

}];
var removeItems = [1001, 1002, 1003];

if (removeItems != "") {

    // run thru dataFromServce loop

    for (var i = 0; i < dataFromServce.length; i++) {
        // if dataFromServce item match removeItems then remove it from dataFromServce
        // TODO: to match every item in removeItems
        if (dataFromServce[i].kod === removeItems[0]) {
            dataFromServce.splice(i, 1);

            i--;

        }

    }
```

this way it checks only one item (removeItems[0]) result should be

```
var dataFromServce = [{
    kod: 1000, teur: 'do0'     
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for filter and includes

```js
const dataFromService = [{
  kod: 1000,
  teur: 'do0'
}, {
  kod: 1001,
  teur: 'do1'
}, {
  kod: 1002,
  teur: 'do2'
}, {
  kod: 1003,
  teur: 'do3'
}];
const removeItems = [1001, 1002, 1003];

const res = dataFromService.filter(({
  kod
}) => !removeItems.includes(kod));
console.log(res);
```

The code in your question is obviously wrong since your dataFromService is invalid, I've fixed that in the answer.

Comment: This snippet has `O(m*n)` complexity, where `m` and `n` are sizes of input and filter. This can be improved to `O(m*log n)` by using hash instead of array for filter or using binary search for key (filter array should be sorted beforehand). Furthermore, if both input and filter come already sorted, improvement is possible to `O(m+n)`

Comment: thank you for your answer @VasilyLiaskovsky , but there is one problem...its not working on internet explorer.

Comment: needs refactor to dataFromService.filter(({kod}) => !removeItems.includes(kod));